# Whats the World Energy for?

Tags: dragon-ball-z-battle-of-z

When at the main menu you see a World Energy Meter that seems to be powering up a giant spirit bomb. This energy is given by players playing the game, but what is the point of the tally? Does something happen when a particular milestone is reached?

Edit: it would also be great to know if the event when a player is requested to give such energy is scripted, random, or triggered some other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The World Energy Meter increases whenever any player completes an Energy Request, which occurs when you complete at least one Special Bonus target in a mission. The more you fill the Energy Gauge in the mission, the more energy you can provide (up to 100 energy), and the more Premium Points you can earn for doing so (which can then be spent on cards in the Premium Collection). The Special Bonus target for each mission unfortunately can only be seen on the Result/Rank screen for a mission after you've actually played it (press Y to bring up Detailed Info, and then scroll down to the bottom to see the Special Bonus for the mission, if they're are any), not from the mission menu,.

Now as to what the World Energy Meter actually means? Not much, really. It's just a tally of the total amount of energy all players have gathered. You do see energy from it seemingly going into an Ultimate Attack if you perform one, but this seems to be purely cosmetic, and doesn't have any real effect on the Ultimate Attack. The counter is currently stopped at '999,999,999,999,999', so it's mostly pointless now anyway (I get the feeling their are a few people with hacked games out there that caused this, as the world energy jumped up a ridiculous amount overnight, and people are certainly not having any issues hacking Weekly Line Up cards that haven't been seen yet into their inventory).

Comment: do you have any sources to any of this information?

Comment: Does personal experience count? I've been playing the game pretty steadily the past couple of days.

Comment: Personal experience does count to some degree, but at 31 reputation, that degree is very small. For what its worth your answer was well written, and I upvoted it, but sources are always nice.\

Comment: Sure, I completely understand that. I just figured I could use the information I'd discovered from my playing the game to help somebody out, particularly since nobody else had attempted to (and the game itself does such a terrible job of explaining how any of it works). This is literally my only visit to this site, purely to answer this question that I stumbled upon when looking something else up associated with the game (hence why my reputation would be so low). Thank you for the upvote though. :-)

Comment: Ah, didn't realise that you were the one asking the question if the first place! Hope I was able to help. :-)